# How to display date correctly with Angular2+?

Tags: angular, forms, date, ngmodel

I'm using Angular2+ to make a Kanban board.

I've decided to add a deadline on tasks then to display it on the board with the format `'yyyy-MM-dd'`.

I've made a form to edit the deadline, and when I use it, the displayed date change in real time because I use `[(ngModel)]` directive.

But the new date is displayed in this format: '`Thu Jul 25 00:00:00 GMT+0200`'.
So I would like to find something to change that OR something to update the information without changing what the user sees.

Comment: Something to look into: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: I tried that, like this: `<input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.deadline | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="minDate" placeholder="Choose a date">`
But I got this error: `Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression`

Comment: You can't put the pipe in a two-way binding, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I also tried this: `<input matInput [ngModel]="task.deadline | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="task.deadline = $event" [value]="task.deadline | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="minDate" placeholder="Choose a date">`

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using a template-driven form, switching to a reactive form means you no longer need the ngModel directive. Angular Material then takes care of the rest, showing the chosen date by default.

If you then want to play around with how the date is displayed, you can either use one of the provided DateAdapters or create your own.

Alternatively, you can separate the DatePicker from the input, or even remove the input part altogether and simply display the chosen date with string interpolation.